# How can I calculate rankings of unique values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, ranking

Lets say I have a simple table with 'appID' and 'userID', which his populated for each app that used by a specific user (ever). (These IDs refer to other tables which have information about app and user which do not matter for this question).

For example:

```
appID  userID
1      1
1      2
2      2
```

Here, we can see app #1 was used by two users, but app #2 was used by one user.

I want to generate statistics for the most commonly used app using a MySQL query, if possible. The query would return a list of sorted results with the appID and the total number of unique users using it.

I did some research but cannot figure out an easy to do this in SQL. If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it. If it requires a very long and involved stored procedure, I may just switch to doing some of the calculations in code (at least initially) since it will be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Why is a lack of research no longer a valid reason for closing questions?

Comment: @Strawberry: See [Should Stack Overflow be awarding “A”s for Effort?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840) and also http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215546

Comment: 'lack of research' is very subjective. True, I only spent a few minutes doing google searches to find an answer to my problem but there are many problems that get solved in that scope of time. If I spent several hours doing more searches (and reading SQL docs) odds are I would have figured this out myself eventually. But writing on question on here got my problem solved in under an hour and I was able to work on something else in the mean time. Seems like a pretty efficient way to go, and I can't see how my post hurts anyone. Keep in mind this is not "homework", its for a personal project.

Comment: In this instance I have to disagree, and I think my position is borne out by the simplicity of the solution provided by eggyal. It's just not credible that you could undertake 'some research' and not find an answer to such a rivial problem. True, we can choose to ignore such questions, but if we want to participate in SO, then we are at least obliged to read them. In my view, this diminishes the resource that is SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT appID, COUNT(*) FROM myTable GROUP BY appID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```